# Could not find gem sqlite3 (~>1.4) x86~mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to make a very simple rails program and meet this problem. When I ran `rails s`, it said to me this error

`Could not find gem sqlite3 (~>1.4) x86~mingw32 in any of the gem sources listed in your gemfile. Run bundle install to install missing gems`

The problem is, when I ran `bundle install`, it auto delete something in the program, and it said that `error : mingw32: key "4A6129F4E4B..." is unknown` and many errors more as you can see in the picture.
[error: mingw32: key 4A6129F4E... is unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEaPr.png)

I follow this link to fix the error, https://www.msys2.org/news/, and successfully.
Then I follow this link https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html and copy all the sqlite file to the folder `C:\Ruby26\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\sqlite3-1.4.2\ext\sqlite3` and compile it by msys, also successfully.

But, when I tried to run `rails s`, it still said to me that error, `Could not find gem sqlite3 (~>1.4) x86~mingw32 in any of the gem sources listed in your gemfile. Run bundle install to install missing gems`

And when I ran `bundle install`, it deleted something in my program.

I am very confusing with this problem, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.